# HTML select dropdown list text wrapping stop working after ajax update

Tags: css, select, drupal-7, html-select

I have a html select drop down list of addresses.  Some addresses are long, which extend out of the parent div border.

I did my homework and find that the css rule solve this:

```
select, option { width: __; }
```

This drop down list is part of an ajax enabled form.  The options for address field will change when user changes in other aera.

Now I find that the css rule works fine so long as the options are same.  Once i do something that cause the select options be changed by ajax, css rule lost it's control.  The select options fields restore back to the original one line form, which break out of the border.

I have checked the html markup  before and after the option changes, to check if the select structure and ids are intact.  It is found that the element structure is same, there is no change in the select element id.

Then why the css rule lost it's hold when the options are changed?

The behavior happens in IE, Firefox and Chrome.

I am using Drupal 7 and it's form, ajax framework.

Update: code

I am useing Drupal 7, so I don't actually write the JS code.  I can only show PHP and CSS here:

Form:

```
$form['shipping_address']['ship_to'] = array(
   '#type' => 'select',
   '#title' => 'Ship To',
   '#options' => $to_options,
   '#required' => true,
   '#default_value' => $selected, 
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ship_to_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'ship_to_address_replace',
    ),  
 );

  $ship_to_address_options = get_ship_to_address_options($selected);
  $form['shipping_address']['ship_to_address'] = array(
   '#type' => 'select',
   '#title' => $to_options[$selected],
   '#options' => $ship_to_address_options,
   '#prefix' => '<div id="ship_to_address_replace">',
   '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['ship_to_address']) ? $form_state['values']['ship_to_address'] : '',
   );
```

'ship_to' controls what options available to 'ship_to_address'.

css:

```
select#edit-ship-to-address, select#edit-bill-to-address {
  width: 60%;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show more code? Using jsfiddle is a good idea too

Answer (score 0):

The CSS rule gets lost probably because the selector isn't valid after the AJAX update. Form element IDs in Drupal will have an auto-incremented number suffix if there are multiple elements with the same name. Inspect the markup and try to adjust your CSS rule. You can even set your own class names to these elements by adding:

```
$form['shipping_address']['ship_to_address']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'my-own-class-to-target-with-css';
```

Also the pasted code does not include the `#suffix` property with a closing , that might lead to other issues, too.